# Can I lazy load html card?/i want to render it on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, lazy-loading

how can I lazy load cards which are written on html?I want them to render after I scroll and first one must be always randered.Can anyone help with this task?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

if you have an image you can use `loading="lazy"` for example: `<img src="URL" loading="lazy">`

also you can use this website for animate On Scroll: https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

Comment: Image is already lazy loading,I whant to lazy load the whole card with price,product info and product image.Thanks by the way